# Setting an Image position using % in swift 3

Tags: swift

I am trying to set an image 15% up on the screen using swift 3. 
The image is a play button to start my game, I want it centered horizontally and 15% up from the bottom, if i set it using a solid constraint when viewing on iPhone 4 & iPhone 7+ the button is in completely different places.

I am using xCode 8.3.2 and Swift 3.

Comment: Do you want the center of the image view 15% from the bottom, or the bottom of the image view 15% from the bottom?

Comment: either will do i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image view's bottom constraint should be equal to the superview's bottom constraint with a multiplier of 0.85.

You can set a constraint in the storyboard with a multiplier like so:

[image: storyboard screenshot]

To initially set up the constraint, I created a constraint between the image view and the super view to center it vertically. Then just adjust the dropdown menus to relate the views as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Create a constraint that sets your button's `.centerY` (or `.bottom`) attribute equal to the `.bottom` of its superview with a multiplier of `0.85` (because 85% of the way from the top is the same as 15% of the way from the bottom).

In code you would do it like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal,
    toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 0.85, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

See [@nathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43767959/1630618) for how to set this up in the Storyboard.

Comment: Might need an expansion on that, how do you set the .centerY (or .bottom)?

Comment: Are you creating the constraint in code on in the Storyboard?

Comment: Then check out @nathan's answer.  You can change the `first item` to use CenterY instead if you like.